# Does someone lose money when I earn money on warrants?

Tags: derivatives

My question is very simple. Does someone lose money when I earn money on warrants? I have tried searching the web but found nothing. I'm guessing the answer is yes. Also this is my first time here. Is this the stack exchange I should ask these types of questions or is their some better alternative? Perhaps money stack exchange?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By warrant I assume you mean a call option on the stock of a company, with the underlying stock being newly issued if the warrant is exercised.  So then it is like asking if someone else loses money when you own the stock of a company and it goes up.  Well, the other shareholders are making less money than if they had not sold you the warrant.  So in that sense , yes.

Edit to address comment:  the situation with listed options is clear: if you are making money, someone else is losing.  It’s a zero sum game.   For stocks and warrants, more nuanced and it depends what you mean.  Yes, if the company is growing profitably, all stockholders are benefiting , so no one is actually losing money to offset your gain.  However as I said, it’s also true that buying a warrant dilutes the other stockholders so you are causing them to make less money than they would otherwise.

Comment: I believe there to be a difference between stocks, warrants and options in regards of how loses and earns money. For stocks I know that one can earn without someone(s) losing for example if the company growths by self investments or one could earn if the company gives out dividends. For warrants (or options as well I guess) then it is pure betting in terms of losing and earning? I make someone a offer and I or the other one will lose money to the other part?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming we are talking about the most basic warrant with payoff of kind
$max(S-K,0)$.

When this kind of warrant is exerised new shares are issued by the company. Does issuing new share result in stock price drop? It all depends on what the company is going to do with the money. Of course when new stock is issued, then company's value is diluted, but it does not mean the market capitalization/stock price will fall.  Public companies issue shares to raise capital that funds their operations, sometimes they issue new shares to further expand themselves or achieve synergy by acquiring other firms. If the acquisitions will significantly increase profitability, the stock price should go up. If that happens, the company can be more efficient with additional capital than it used to be. **BUT** If the company is raising capital without a viable plan for the use of the money, then it is opposite, the investing public may sell of shares, driving down the stock price.
Therefore it all depends on what company is going to do with the money and it's effect on marginal EPS.

**To sum up**:
If EPS goes up after the warrant was exercised, then stock price should go up, if it goes down then stock price should fall.

There are also different kind of warrants, like puttable warrant (and others), with payoff of kind $max(K-S,0)$, that are recognized as liability in financial statements. This kind of warrant won't provide any benefit for the company, the company loses money when they are exercised.

References:

[GAAP: How to Classify Warrants](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/gaap-classify-warrants-81298.html)

[What Happens to the Share Price When New Shares Are Issued?](https://finance.zacks.com/debt-vs-equity-issue-important-6394.html)